# Change Qtableview vertical header appearness

Tags: qt, qtableview

i have a qtableview , i wanna to change vertical header to accept icon

means, when the row is seleted, an icon "arrow up/down" showing

how i can do that

i'm using Qsqlquerymodel and Qtableview widget

Answer (score 0):

You should get header view (::verticalHeader), then get header model (::model) and set Qt::DecorationRole for necessary row (::setData)

Comment: what's wrong her  ProduitView->verticalHeader()->setStyleSheet("::section:checked { background-color: black;background-image: url(imgs/arrow.png)}");

Comment: Invalid class selector. Try QHeadeView::section:checked or QTableView::section:checked

Comment: i have used this code        ProduitView->verticalHeader()->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section:checked {"
                                                 " background-color: black;     }"
                                                 " background-image: url(imgs/arrow.png)"
                                                 );   but the only part of the background colr shown , could i remove the index number from vertical header?? if so, how i can do that

Comment: Once again - create custom model. No stylesheet required

Comment: sorry, but really i can't do that can you give me an example

Comment: Could you update your question and provide code (what you already tried)

Comment: check this http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/55406-how-i-can-chagne-Qtableview-horizontal-header-text-as-well-as-remove-Indexes-vHeader